# php (or c++) how to read data of multiple formats from binary file

Tags: php, c++, binary

i have a question that i cant find the answer
i use the following code to write data from database to binary file:

```
$data = array();
$prev = 1;
$i=0;

$query="select wc.MAC, ws.SIGNAL_STRENGTH, ws.ID, ws.USER_SCAN from wifi_cell as wc, wifi_scan as ws where ws.WIFI_CELL=wc.ID";
$result=kmysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $data[] = array(0,0,0,null,$row['MAC'],$row['SIGNAL_STRENGTH'],null,$row['USER_SCAN']);
    $i++;
}

mysql_free_result($result);

$j=0;
$query="select ul.LATITUDE, ul.LONGITUDE,ul.ALTITUDE, ul.TIME from user_location as ul where 1";
$result=kmysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    while ($j<$i) {
        if ($data[$j][7] == $prev) {
            $data[$j][0] = $row['LATITUDE'];
            $data[$j][1] = $row['LONGITUDE'];
            $data[$j][2] = $row['ALTITUDE'];
            $data[$j][3] = $row['TIME'];
            $j++;
        }
        else {
            $prev = $data[$j][7];
            break;
        }

    }
}

mysql_free_result($result);

$handle = fopen('C:\\Users\\Duc Nguyen\\Desktop\\text1.bin', 'r+');
ftruncate($handle, 0);
fclose($handle);

for ($j=0;$j<$i;$j++) {
    $data[$j][0] = pack("d*",$data[$j][0]);
    $data[$j][1] = pack("d*",$data[$j][1]);
    $data[$j][2] = pack("d*",$data[$j][2]);
    $data[$j][3] = pack("A*",$data[$j][3]);
    $data[$j][4] = pack("Z*",$data[$j][4]);
    $data[$j][5] = pack("d*",$data[$j][5]);
    $data[$j][6] = pack("A*",$data[$j][6]);
    $data[$j][7] = pack("d*",$data[$j][7]);

    file_put_contents('C:\\Users\\Duc Nguyen\\Desktop\\text1.bin', $data[$j], FILE_APPEND);
}
```

but now the binary file contains many types of data and i dont know how to read it. can you please show me how to read them in php? and also c++?

Comment: Check out the [documentation for the pack() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php). It explains how the function works. I would also recommend getting a hex editor to help you look into the file. Hex Workshop is a good one but commercial. xvi32 is a decent free one.

Comment: I just realized you also said you want to read in PHP. In that case just use the [unpack() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php). The info above is if you want to read using C++.

Comment: Thank you for the c++ stuffs. I will check them tomorrow. But in php, how can i use unpack because i got different formats in the file?

Comment: What do you mean? The code you posted above is the code that was used to write the file, so just use the same formats in unpack() to unpack your data.

Comment: in the binary file i got hundreds of data. i tried     
    $s = file_get_contents('C:\\Users\\Duc Nguyen\\Desktop\\text1.bin');
    $arr = unpack("d*/d*/d*/A*/Z*/d*/A*/d*", $s);
and some other ways but i cant get the data back. can you show me the way to use it?

Comment: I already gave you some useful information; I'm not going to do your work for you. Also, for future reference, please put your code into your original post, not in comments, as code in comments is difficult to read.

Comment: I will point out that you need to use a loop, just as your original code does.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It's my first time working with binary file. The file is just the input for my c++ program so I really need it as soon as possible. Anw, have a nice day.